# 文字列をtimedelta に変換する方法

Tags: python

python で　「文字列　を　timedelta型」 に簡単に変換する方法はあるでしょうか？
これはあまり需要がないのでしょうか？
「timedelta型 を　文字列」に変更する方法はＷＥＢで散見されました。
文字列は「01:23:15」　といったデータです。１時間２３分１５秒といったデータです。

Comment: [pandas.to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) を使うのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: to_timedelta を使うのが一番シンプルになりそうです。ありがとうございます。使っていきます。

Answer (score 2):

前に同じようなことを考えたときにPythonのマニュアルを見ながらこれだったら出来そうと思って
作ったのが下記のコードでした。datetimeの引き算がtimedeltaになることを利用しています

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
stamp = '01:23:15'
t = datetime.strptime('2019-01-01 '+stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime(2019,1,1)
print(type(t) , t)

<class 'datetime.timedelta'> 1:23:15
```

Answer (score 1):

標準ライブラリのみを利用して変換する方法です。この方法では、 `:` を区切り文字としてパースしております。

```py
import datetime

data = "01:23:15"
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, data.split(":"))
td = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
print(type(td),td)
```